# Issue with pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I have installed PostgresSQL version 12.3 for MAC OS Catalina 10.15.4. I am trying to restore the database dvdrental from https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/. I unzipped the dvdrental.zip file. I am executing the following commands from within the bin directory:

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d dvdrental /Users/programmer27/Downloads/dvdrental.zip   
pg_restore -U postgres -d dvdrental /Users/programmer27/Downloads/dvdrental
```

I am getting an error message:

> -bash: pg_restore: command not found

I am not sure if pg_restore command is working, even though I see it in the bin directory.

Sorry I'm asking a basic question. I'm just very confused.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is an issue with your installation of postgresql – could you explain how you installed it?  Also note that [the current directory isn't in your PATH by default.](https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default)

Comment: I went to this website: https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads   Downloaded postgresql-12.3-1-osx.dmg for MAC OS X version 12.3. Installed Postgresql, and left the installation path untouched. Once the installation was complete, I moved pgAdmin 4 to my applications folder. I started pgAdmin 4 from the application folder. I hope this is enough information. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: As mentioned on the page you downloaded it from "*you need to extract it to  dvdrental.tar*" so `unzip` the archive first. Then you need to specify the full path to the `pg_restore` command, rather then relying it to be included in the `PATH` - that has nothing to do with Postgres though. That is basic command line knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your help!